# Multilingual search in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, recommendation-engine

I want to search for "Salt" in my app (using elastic search). I want to search in my native language. So when I search "namak", I should get the result of all products related to "salt".

Comment: Creating a new text or keyword field with values in your native language is the easiest way I can think of.

Comment: I guess you mean using a dictionary with key as the keyword and values as similar products. Right? I thought of this solution but can we look for a better solution.

Comment: No, I do mean creating a new field in elasticsearch. I'll add an answer because formatting code snippets in comments is gonna get ugly otherwise

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of would be adding a field to your elasticsearch that contains the same words as the english ones, but in your native language. The easiest way to do that is probably to change data before it is loaded into elasticsearch.

Example using python and pandas, and assuming you have a dictionnary named `dic` that maps english words to your native tongue's words (e.g. `{"Salt": "namak"}`), you'd simply do :

```py
df["other_language"] = df["english"].replace(dic)
```

And then proceed and load `df` into elasticsearch as you would normally do.

In elasticsearch, what then happens is that every document having `Salt` in one of its fields now also has `namak` in the field `other_language`, thus, searching for `namak` filters out the exact same documents as searching for `Salt` would.